# How to structure and ARP request packet in C

Tags: c, network-programming, arp, wifi

Today I was investing a little more time to learn about ARP packets. To understand it's structure I tried to build one on myself in C using `libpcap`.  I structured a simple ARP request packet and used `pcap_inject` function to send the packet. This function returns the number of bytes that are sent.

When I debug my code I saw that my packet was 42 bytes long. I search the Internet a bit and couldn't find a answer that tells me if this is the appropriate size for an ARP request or not. Even the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) confused me a little. And the I discovered this post. From the answer provided by the user:

> - If the ARP message is to be sent in an untagged frame then the frame overhead itself is 18 bytes. That would result in a frame of
>     28+18=46 bytes without padding. Additional 18 bytes of padding are
>     necessary in this case to bloat the frame to the 64 byte length.
> - If the ARP message is to be sent in an 802.1Q-tagged frame then the frame overhead is 22 bytes, resulting in the total frame size of
>     28+22=50 bytes. In this case, the padding needs to be 14 bytes long.
> - If the ARP message is to be sent in a double-tagged frame then the frame overhead is 26 bytes, resulting in the total frame size of 54
>     bytes. In this case, the padding needs to be 10 bytes long.

My question is what do I have to do in this situation. Do  I have to use padding or not?

Bellow I post the structure of my packet.

```
#define ETH_P_ARP 0x0806 /* Address Resolution packet */
#define ARP_HTYPE_ETHER 1  /* Ethernet ARP type */
#define ARP_PTYPE_IPv4 0x0800 /* Internet Protocol packet */

/* Ethernet frame header */
typedef struct {
   uint8_t dest_addr[ETH_ALEN]; /* Destination hardware address */
   uint8_t src_addr[ETH_ALEN];  /* Source hardware address */
   uint16_t frame_type;   /* Ethernet frame type */
} ether_hdr;

/* Ethernet ARP packet from RFC 826 */
typedef struct {
   uint16_t htype;   /* Format of hardware address */
   uint16_t ptype;   /* Format of protocol address */
   uint8_t hlen;    /* Length of hardware address */
   uint8_t plen;    /* Length of protocol address */
   uint16_t op;    /* ARP opcode (command) */
   uint8_t sha[ETH_ALEN];  /* Sender hardware address */
   uint32_t spa;   /* Sender IP address */
   uint8_t tha[ETH_ALEN];  /* Target hardware address */
   uint32_t tpa;   /* Target IP address */
} arp_ether_ipv4;
```

In the end I just copy each structure member in the bellow order and send the packet:

```
void packageARP(unsigned char *buffer, ether_hdr *frameHeader, arp_ether_ipv4 *arp_packet, size_t *bufferSize) {
  unsigned char *cp;
  size_t packet_size;

  cp = buffer;

  packet_size = sizeof(frameHeader->dest_addr) 
                + sizeof(frameHeader->src_addr)  
                + sizeof(frameHeader->frame_type)
                + sizeof(arp_packet->htype)       
                + sizeof(arp_packet->ptype)    
                + sizeof(arp_packet->hlen)        
                + sizeof(arp_packet->plen)       
                + sizeof(arp_packet->op)        
                + sizeof(arp_packet->sha)        
                + sizeof(arp_packet->spa)         
                + sizeof(arp_packet->tha)        
                + sizeof(arp_packet->tpa);
  /*
   *  Copy the Ethernet frame header to the buffer.
   */
  memcpy(cp, &(frameHeader->dest_addr), sizeof(frameHeader->dest_addr));
  cp += sizeof(frameHeader->dest_addr);

  memcpy(cp, &(frameHeader->src_addr), sizeof(frameHeader->src_addr));
  cp += sizeof(frameHeader->src_addr);

  /* Normal Ethernet-II framing */
  memcpy(cp, &(frameHeader->frame_type), sizeof(frameHeader->frame_type));
  cp += sizeof(frameHeader->frame_type);


  /*
   *  Add the ARP data.
   */
  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->htype), sizeof(arp_packet->htype));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->htype);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->ptype), sizeof(arp_packet->ptype));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->ptype);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->hlen), sizeof(arp_packet->hlen));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->hlen);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->plen), sizeof(arp_packet->plen));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->plen);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->op), sizeof(arp_packet->op));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->op);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->sha), sizeof(arp_packet->sha));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->sha);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->spa), sizeof(arp_packet->spa));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->spa);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->tha), sizeof(arp_packet->tha));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->tha);

  memcpy(cp, &(arp_packet->tpa), sizeof(arp_packet->tpa));
  cp += sizeof(arp_packet->tpa);

  *bufferSize = packet_size;
}
```

Is this the correct way of structuring an ARP request packet?

Comment: I have a comment/question, you just used `uint8_t` on "Sender hardware address". However, wherever i look, i see that hardware addresses are of 16/32 bits, why you used 8 bits unsigned integer instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct structure -- *except* that the C compiler is free to insert padding in order to ensure structure members are placed at the most efficient boundaries. In particular, `spa` and `tpa` are not at natural 32-bit boundaries (due to the preceding 6-byte MAC address fields) and so the compiler might want to insert two bytes of padding before each.

If you are using gcc, you can ensure that doesn't happen with `__attribute__((packed))`:

```
struct {
       [fields]
}  __attribute__((packed)) arp_ether_ipv4;
```

Other compilers might have a different but equivalent mechanism (a `#pragma` directive for example).

The ARP payload should be 28 bytes. Adding the 14-byte ethernet header, that gives 42 total bytes. As your cite said, an 802.1Q (VLAN) header inserts an additional 4 bytes and a "double-tagged" frame (not common outside of Internet service providers) will add 2 X 4 = 8 bytes. If you're on an ordinary endpoint machine, you wouldn't typically add these headers anyway. The IT department will have configured your switches to automatically insert/remove these headers as needed.

The 42 bytes will get padded *automatically* to 64 bytes (Ethernet minimum packet size) by your network driver. 64 is actually 60 + the 4-byte Ethernet FCS [frame checksum]. (The post you cited is apparently including the 4-byte FCS in their calculations, which is why their numbers seem whack.)

Also, don't forget to use network byte order for all `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` fields: (`ntohs` and `ntohl`)

Comment: Hi Gil, thanks for your answer. I added the `attribute` field as you proposed. For `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` fields I use `htons`. Is this wrong? I also wanted to ask what should be the value of target MAC as this is what we want to find out. I use `unsigned char arp_tha[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`

Comment: `htons` is host-to-network-*short* (16-bit / uint16_t). `htonl` is host-to-network-long (32-bit / uint32_t). Setting `tha` to all zeroes is correct. Its value in the request should be ignored anyway. That (the target hardware address) is what you're seeking by doing the ARP transaction.